# Import large .sql file into MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-restore

I have been given a **VERY** large mysql backup file. It is ~630 MB... I guess someone thought it was a good idea to store images in a database... Anyway, I need to restore the data somehow in MySQL. But i can't get it done because of the filesize.

At first i tried to do it with MySQL Workbench. But when i try to import the file it gives me the following error:

> Could not allocate xxxxx bytes to read file C:\backup.sql

Then i tried to do it through command prompt. I entered the following in `cmd`:

```
C:\> mysql -u user -pPassword database < C:\backups.sql
```

That eventually gives me the following warning:

> ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 68230: MySQL server has gone away

Guess that is also because of the big filesize?

I have no other ideas on how to restore the data. Is that still possible somehow?

Comment: Open it using a text-editor and split the file in parts. Pay attention you keep having a valid syntax.

Comment: How long does it take before it _goes away_? I have restored 1.2GB sql file btw using mysql client so it is definitely possible.

Comment: Im not a MySQL expert but found this article which relates to time out settings in the config file which might be the cause of your problem given the size of the file... http://thenitai.com/2010/10/31/a-solution-to-mysql-error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away/

Comment: @SalmanA It takes around 30 seconds before the warning appears. I just noticed that it did a partial restore. But for some reason it just "goes away" after 30 minutes.

Comment: @bUKaneer Thanks, that actually looks like it might work. I'm trying to find those settings right now. Hopfully it works out for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Increasing the [`wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and/or [`interactive_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout) should help. First check the current value:

```
C:\> mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -proot

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';
```

If this is very low (e.g. 30 seconds) then increase it (e.g. 5 minutes):

```
mysql> SET SESSION wait_timeout = 300;
mysql> SET SESSION interactive_timeout = 300;
```

Then execute your SQL file:

```
mysql> \. database.sql
```

Comment: I also changed the `interactive_timeout` to something big. But that with the `wait_timeout` didn't do the trick for me. After that i also changed the 'connect_timeout` from `10` to `10000` and that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had a 3.5G dump file, I tried to import it with PhpMyAdmin and MySql workbench but without success. So I just used the console to run it

```
# mysql -u user_name -pYour_passwd your_db < your_dump.sql
```

and it works great

Comment: where should I put your_dump.sql file?